# scan a variable and use it in do while loop

Tags: c, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char ans='n';
 do
 {
     printf("\n Enter yes or no:");
     scanf("%c",ans);
     printf("\n entered %c",ans);
 }while(ans == 'y');
}
```

As do while the loop is getting exccuted and that scanf is working and prnting my answer (say my answer is y) , its coming for 2nd time but not doing the scan and getting exited . May i know the reason for this ? why it is happening and what is the correct way to handle the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

First up, you're missing a `&` in the scanf:

```
scanf("%c", &ans);
            ^
```

Second, you're not handling the newline, and the `%c` format specifier doesn't ignore blanks. So you read a character, press return, and the next `scanf` is immediately satisfied by that `\n`. To ignore blanks in `scanf` try:

```
scanf(" %c", &ans);
       ^
```

Comment: thanks it works, so only for strint & is not required when we scan for all others it is required.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you missing the `&address-of` operator as indicated in other answers, but you're also missing the return value checks. Consider if a user presses CTRL+Z in Windows, or CTRL+d in Linux, to close stdin. Your loop would run infinitely and freeze your app ;)

```
if (scanf("%c", &ans) != 1) {
    break;
}
```

Alternatively, I would suggest using `getchar` because it's far cleaner:

```
int main(void) { /* NOTE: There is no "void main()" entrance point in C. main should always return 'int'. */
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use *fflush(stdin)* to flush those return feeds.

But when you are inputting a single character, then why not use *getchar()*?

---

EDIT:
As correctly pointed out by  cnicutar here, fflush(stdin) has undefined behaviour. There doesn't seem to be any inbuilt function to take care of that and hence must be taken care of in the code itself.

One example could be:

```
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Thanks for pointing that out there!

Comment: The `getchar` is certainly a good suggestion but [`fflush(stdin)` is undefined](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html), you shouldn't recommend it.

Comment: **Don't use fflush(stdin)**. fflush is only defined for use on files open for output. stdin is open for input, but not output. Hence, fflush(stdin) is undefined behaviour.